# The problems scanned by sonar scanner are much less than those scanned by soanr: soanr

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarscanner

The problems scanned by sonar scanner are much less than those scanned by soanr: soanr

I use sonar scanner and soanr: sonar commands through the same jenkins, but their results are different.

This is my sonar scanner command：sonar.projectKey

```
sonar.projectName
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.language=java
sonar.sources
sonar.java.binariesde
```

This is my Maven command：

```
mvn clean install sonar:sonar
```

For the same project, soanr scanner had only 71 problems and maven soanr had 107 problems.

Comment: Configuration issue, need to define scanner configuration.

Comment: Is there a lack of code paths to configure scans?

Comment: Please fallow the link. https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101

Comment: Also follow this link https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/rules/

Comment: You mean the problem is caused by Sonar's scanning rules? Is the soanr rule used by sonar scanner different from that used by maven

Comment: yes, you need to change the rule

Comment: I will check it,thank you very much